# UIWebview Loading same html page again and again?

Tags: html, ios, objective-c, caching, uiwebview

I have a `UIWebView` in my viewcontroller, and when I tried to open an `epub` file it shows correctly but every epub thereafter shows the same cover page (first page) and its contents are different.

Why is this happeneing? Is there cache inside the codes?

**In chapter class**

```
- (void) loadChapterWithWindowSize:(CGRect)theWindowSize fontPercentSize:(int) theFontPercentSize
{
    //  [[NSURLCache sharedURLCache] removeAllCachedResponses];
    fontPercentSize = theFontPercentSize;
    windowSize =theWindowSize;
    // NSLog(@"webviewSize: %f * %f, fontPercentSize: %d", theWindowSize.size.width, theWindowSize.size.height,theFontPercentSize);
    UIWebView* webView = [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:theWindowSize];
    [webView setDelegate:self];
    NSURLRequest* urlRequest = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:spinePath]];

    //CODE FOR IGNORING CACHE

    //NSURLRequest* urlRequest ;
    //urlRequest=[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:spinePath] cachePolicy:NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringCacheData timeoutInterval:10000];

    //[webView loadRequest:urlRequest];
    NSLog(@"%@",spinePath);//html pahe path
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:spinePath]];
};

- (void)webView:(UIWebView *)webView didFailLoadWithError:(NSError *)error{
    [webView release];
}

- (void) webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView*)webView
{
    [webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"document.open();document.close()"];
    [[NSURLCache sharedURLCache] removeAllCachedResponses];
    sharedManager=[Mymanager sharedManager];
    NSString *varMySheet = @"var mySheet = document.styleSheets[0];";
    NSString *addCSSRule =  @"function addCSSRule(selector, newRule) {"
    "if (mySheet.addRule) {"
    "mySheet.addRule(selector, newRule);"                               // For Internet Explorer
    "} else {"
    "ruleIndex = mySheet.cssRules.length;"
    "mySheet.insertRule(selector + '{' + newRule + ';}', ruleIndex);"   // For Firefox, Chrome, etc.
    "}"
    "}";

    // NSLog(@"w:%f h:%f", webView.bounds.size.width, webView.bounds.size.height);

    NSString *insertRule1 = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"addCSSRule('html', 'padding: 0px; height: %fpx; -webkit-column-gap: 0px; -webkit-column-width: %fpx;')", webView.frame.size.height, webView.frame.size.width];
    NSString *insertRule2 = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"addCSSRule('p', 'text-align: justify;')"];
    NSString *setTextSizeRule = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"addCSSRule('body', '-webkit-text-size-adjust: %d%%;')",fontPercentSize];


    [webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:varMySheet];
    [webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:addCSSRule];
    [webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:insertRule1];
    [webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:insertRule2];
    [webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:setTextSizeRule];

    int totalWidth = [[webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"document.documentElement.scrollWidth"] intValue];
    pageCount = (int)((float)totalWidth/webView.bounds.size.width);

    //NSLog(@"Chapter %d: %@ -> %d pages", chapterIndex, title, pageCount);

    [webView dealloc];
    [delegate chapterDidFinishLoad:self];
}
```

**in my viewocntroller class**

```
- (void) chapterDidFinishLoad:(Chapter *)chapter{
i=i+1;

    NSLog(@"iteration%d",i);
    NSLog(@"%d",[loadedEpub.spineArray count]);
    loadingProgressBar=loadingProgressBar+1;
    sharedManager=[Mymanager sharedManager];
    NSLog(@"%d",sharedManager.coverPageloadCount);
    //sharedManager.coverPageloadCount++;
    totalPagesCount+=chapter.pageCount;
    sharedManager.TotalPageNumber=totalPagesCount;
    if(chapter.chapterIndex + 1 < [loadedEpub.spineArray count]){
        [[loadedEpub.spineArray objectAtIndex:chapter.chapterIndex+1] setDelegate:self];
        [[loadedEpub.spineArray objectAtIndex:chapter.chapterIndex+1] loadChapterWithWindowSize:webView.bounds fontPercentSize:currentTextSize];
        [currentPageLabel setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"?/%d", totalPagesCount]];
    } 
    else {
        [currentPageLabel setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d/%d",[self getGlobalPageCount], totalPagesCount]];
        [pageSlider setValue:(float)100*(float)[self getGlobalPageCount]/(float)totalPagesCount animated:YES];
        paginating = NO;
        //NSLog(@"Pagination Ended!");
}

    - (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)thewebView{

    // [self TextureModes];



    NSUserDefaults *menuUserDefaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    if([menuUserDefaults boolForKey:@"btnM1"]){
        [webView setOpaque:NO];
        [webView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
        NSString *jsString2 = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].style.webkitTextFillColor= 'black'"];
        [webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:jsString2];

    }
    else{
        NSUserDefaults *userDefaults2 = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
        [userDefaults2 setBool:NO forKey:@"btnM1"];
        [userDefaults2 synchronize];

        [webView setOpaque:NO];
        [webView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor blackColor]];
        NSString *jsString = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].style.webkitTextFillColor= 'white'"];
        [webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:jsString];

    }

    if(sharedManager.textureFlag==1)
    {
        webView.backgroundColor=[UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"darkWoodP.png"]];
    }else if(sharedManager.textureFlag==2)
    {
        webView.backgroundColor=[UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"paperP.png"]];
    }

    NSString *varMySheet = @"var mySheet = document.styleSheets[0];";

    NSString *addCSSRule =  @"function addCSSRule(selector, newRule) {"
    "if (mySheet.addRule) {"
    "mySheet.addRule(selector, newRule);"                               // For Internet Explorer
    "} else {"
    "ruleIndex = mySheet.cssRules.length;"
    "mySheet.insertRule(selector + '{' + newRule + ';}', ruleIndex);"   // For Firefox, Chrome, etc.
    "}"
    "}";


    NSString *insertRule1 = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"addCSSRule('html', 'padding: 0px; height: %fpx; -webkit-column-gap: 0px; -webkit-column-width: %fpx;')", webView.frame.size.height, webView.frame.size.width];
    NSString *insertRule2 = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"addCSSRule('p', 'text-align: justify;')"];
    NSString *setTextSizeRule = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"addCSSRule('body', '-webkit-text-size-adjust: %d%%;')", currentTextSize];
    NSString *setHighlightColorRule = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"addCSSRule('highlight', 'background-color: yellow;')"];


    [webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:varMySheet];

    [webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:addCSSRule];

    [webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:insertRule1];

    [webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:insertRule2];

    [webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:setTextSizeRule];

    [webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:setHighlightColorRule];
    NSString *padding = @"document.body.style.padding='30px 30px 30px 30px';";
    NSString *paddingtop = @"document.body.style.padding-top='85px';";
    NSString *paddingbottom = @"document.body.style.margin-bottom='85px';";
    [webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:padding];
    [webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:paddingtop];
    [webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:paddingbottom];
    if(currentSearchResult!=nil){
        //  NSLog(@"Highlighting %@", currentSearchResult.originatingQuery);
        [webView highlightAllOccurencesOfString:currentSearchResult.originatingQuery];
    }


    totalWidth = [[webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"document.documentElement.scrollWidth"] intValue];
    //  NSLog(@"%d %f",totalWidth,webView.bounds.size.width);
    pagesInCurrentSpineCount = (int)((float)totalWidth/webView.bounds.size.width);
    [self gotoPageInCurrentSpine:currentPageInSpineIndex];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try an experiment: instead of reloading the web view, release it and replace it with a new one (properly niling and setting delegates). If the new web view shows the same content it must be the files. If that fixes things you have now one way to fix it.